# Nesting if statements - cannot get the nested statements to execute

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to get the below nested statements to work, but am having issues getting them to execute past the first statement. I tried nesting the statements but just the first if executes. Any feedback about formatting is greatly appreciated, I understand that there may be a more efficient way of achieving this, but I have to execute the code using nested statements.

```
package incometax;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class IncomeTax {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,###,000.00");

String singleStatus = "single";
String marriedStatus = "married";
String maritalStatus = "";
double annualIncome = 0;
double taxAmount = 0;

System.out.println("Please enter your martial status: ");
maritalStatus = scnr.next();
 if (maritalStatus.compareTo(singleStatus) == 0){
     System.out.println("Please enter your annual income: ");
     annualIncome = scnr.nextDouble();

         if (annualIncome <= 30000){
         taxAmount = (annualIncome * .15);
         System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +        
         df.format(annualIncome) + " your tax is " + "$ " +   
         df.format(taxAmount));

             if (annualIncome > 30000){
             taxAmount = (annualIncome * .25);
             System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +   
             df.format(annualIncome) + 
             " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
             }
         }
         else {
              if (maritalStatus.compareTo(marriedStatus) == 0){

                 if(annualIncome <= 30000){
                 taxAmount = (annualIncome * .12);
                 System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ "  
                 +  df.format(annualIncome) + 
                 " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));

                     if(annualIncome > 30000){
                     taxAmount = (annualIncome * .20);
                     System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+  
                     "$ " +  df.format(annualIncome) + 
                     " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
                     }
                  }
               }
             }
        }  
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: If your indentation was consistent it would be easier to see what was going on.

Comment: You have conditions that can never be true. For example, inside the block of `if (annualIncome <= 30000)`, you have `if (annualIncome > 30000)`, which will always be false, since `annualIncome` didn't change.

Comment: Don't use nested statements, change them to simpler ones, using the early-return pattern.

Comment: Your IDE should be able to fix your indentation for you. In my Eclipse (on Mac) command-shift-F does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are going into the first `if` when `annualIncome <= 30000`. But the condition in the nested if is `annualIncome > 30000`. This will always be false. Try `if else` instead of nested `if`

```
if (annualIncome <= 30000) {
    taxAmount = (annualIncome * .15);
    System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +        
        df.format(annualIncome) + " your tax is " + "$ " +   
        df.format(taxAmount));
}
else {
    taxAmount = (annualIncome * .25);
    System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +   
        df.format(annualIncome) + 
        " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have misplaced the parenthesis of if statement.
Try this code it should work

```
package incometax;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class IncomeTax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,###,000.00");

        String singleStatus = "single";
        String marriedStatus = "married";
        String maritalStatus = "";
        double annualIncome = 0;
        double taxAmount = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter your martial status: ");
        maritalStatus = scnr.next();
        if (maritalStatus.compareTo(singleStatus) == 0){
            System.out.println("Please enter your annual income: ");
            annualIncome = scnr.nextDouble();

            if (annualIncome <= 30000){
                taxAmount = (annualIncome * .15);
                System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +        
                df.format(annualIncome) + " your tax is " + "$ " +   
                df.format(taxAmount));
            } else {
                taxAmount = (annualIncome * .25);
                System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ " +   
                df.format(annualIncome) + 
                " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
            }
        } else if (maritalStatus.compareTo(marriedStatus) == 0){

            if(annualIncome <= 30000){
                taxAmount = (annualIncome * .12);
                System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+ "$ "  
                +  df.format(annualIncome) + 
                " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
            } else {
                taxAmount = (annualIncome * .20);
                System.out.println("Based on annual income of "+  
                "$ " +  df.format(annualIncome) + 
                " your tax is " + "$ " + df.format(taxAmount));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A decent IDE will be able to format your code to make this sort of nesting issue more apparent.

It may not be part of the question but you also have several repeated lines of code, take a look in to methods. For example the following is cleaner (note there is no validation on the marital status or the annual income)

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncomeTax
{

    private static final DecimalFormat DF = new DecimalFormat("#,###,000.00");

    private static final String SINGLE_STATUS = "single";
    private static final String MARRIED_STATUS = "married";

    private static final double SINGLE_LOW_RATE = .15;
    private static final double SINGLE_HIGH_RATE = .25;

    private static final double MARRIED_LOW_RATE = .12;
    private static final double MARRIED_HIGH_RATE = .20;

    private static final int LOWER_BRACKET = 30000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String maritalStatus;
        double annualIncome;

        System.out.println(
            "Please enter your martial status: ");
        maritalStatus = scnr.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter your annual income: ");
        annualIncome = scnr.nextDouble();

        if (SINGLE_STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase(maritalStatus))
        {
            printTaxRate(annualIncome, SINGLE_LOW_RATE, SINGLE_HIGH_RATE);
        } else
        {
            if (MARRIED_STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase(maritalStatus))
            {
                printTaxRate(annualIncome, MARRIED_LOW_RATE, MARRIED_HIGH_RATE);
            }
        }
    }

    private static double calcTaxAmount(double annualIncome, double taxRate)
    {
        return annualIncome * taxRate;
    }

    private static void printTaxRate(double annualIncome, double lowRate, double highRate)
    {
        double taxAmount;
        if (annualIncome <= LOWER_BRACKET)
        {
            taxAmount = calcTaxAmount(annualIncome, lowRate);
        } else
        {
            taxAmount = calcTaxAmount(annualIncome, highRate);
        }

        System.out.println("Based on annual income of " + "$ "
            + DF.format(annualIncome)
            + " your tax is " + "$ " + DF.format(taxAmount));
    }
}
```